# HTTPS CNAME setup for CDN

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, cname-record, cdn

### Background

I need to host some files on our CDN (edgecast) which will be available over HTTPS. I would usually accomplish this by using the provided CDN url, i.e. `https://wav22.233d.edgecast.com/...`.

### The Problem

I recently tried to use a CNAME e.x.`cdn.somesite.com` so instead of using an ugly URL I could use a sub domain of the current site. I have tried to set this up but keep getting a certificate error as the certificate seems to only be issued to the `*.somesite.com` url and not the edgecast CDN url its resolving too.

I have tried to contact edgecast but they have been disgustingly slow at responding. Maybe if I bought an SSL certificate for the edgecast domain name from them, but then I figured it would invalidate due to the CNAME that was pointing too it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're a large enterprise customer, getting a CDN to set up an SSL on their systems for you is very unlikely. This isn't something you can do for them, their servers need to be configured with your SSL certificate and private key to present it on your behalf.

No one really cares about the URLs of the images on your site, anyways.

Comment: It's not for a website, the `cdn.somesite.com` URL is being placed into an application and this way I can have control over the URL. If, for example, I wanted to change CDN providers I wouldn't need to update my application on peoples devices.

Comment: It would cost you a bit in latency, but you could have application point at a server (or servers) you control that does nothing other than sends out HTTP redirects to the CDN.

Comment: But then the resources would be served over HTTP which sort of defeats the purpose. Otherwise I would have just used the HTTP CDN URL.

Comment: @Hzmy I'd suggest having the CDN URL being an application setting. Have your app periodically check a URL for an update to the CDN path.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I needed a wildcard HTTPS certificate for `*.somesite.com` and this then needed to be placed on the CDN server.